# Upload an image to Azure Functions using HttpRequest from Postman

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I'm having a hard time getting an image uploaded to Azure Functions using `HttpRequest`. I'm specifically using `HttpRequest` because that's what the VS templates use. I've simplified the problem to a simple test case with Postman.

Function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequest req)
{
    return new CreatedResult("", req.Form.Files[0].OpenReadStream());
}
```

Postman:

```
Method: POST
URL: [Function URL]
Headers:
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Body: binary with image selected
```

So what should happen is that I select a file to upload, I click "Send" to upload it to the Azure Function, which should automatically return the stream and display the picture in the Postman response.

But when I call it from Postman, an exception is thrown when it tries to read the stream:

> "System.IO.InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary.\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, Int32 lengthLimit)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()\r\n   at [My code]"

Now if I were to switch this to use `HttpRequestMessage` like the old Azure Function templates and use `req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`, it works like a charm.

But since the new templates use `HttpRequest`, this question is focused on the use of `HttpRequest` and its correct use. So how can I use `HttpRequest` to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman provides a way to upload form-data, choose type as File and upload the image.(No need to set headers)

[image]

See this request header in Fiddler, Postman sets boundary automatically.

```
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------970956809380964389175281
```

If we upload binary with content type header, the header is `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, so that we got error of missing boundary.